# model_unpickle() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, serialization

I'm facing this error bellow with celery 3.1.25 and 4.1.0, this happen if I set serializing with pickle (I know is a problem with security) but I use a library that needs this kind of serialization to work with files, anyone have solved this problem?.

Will add my freeze at the bottom of the question.

Thank you

```
    Can't decode message body: DecodeError(TypeError('model_unpickle() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)', , (('data_importer', 'FileHistory'),)),) [type:u'application/x-python-serialize' encoding:u'binary' headers:{u'origin': u'gen29@f6876eb537fc', u'lang': u'py', u'task': u'data_importer_task', u'group': None, u'root_id': u'655b3b91-b48e-41c3-a893-ab7b5bdfdf79', u'expires': None, u'retries': 0, u'timelimit': [3600, None], u'argsrepr': u'()', u'eta': None, u'parent_id': None, u'id': u'655b3b91-b48e-41c3-a893-ab7b5bdfdf79', u'kwargsrepr': u"{'source': , 'importer': , 'file': , 'owner': >, 'subproject': , 'action': 'u'}"}]

    body: '\x80\x02)}q\x01(U\x06sourceq\x02cdjango.db.models.base\nmodel_unpickle\nq\x03U\rdata_importerq\x04U\x0bFileHistoryq\x05\x86\x85Rq\x06}q\x07(U\x06statusq\x08K\x01U\x0bfile_uploadq\tXI\x00\x00\x00upload_history/map_su/2018/02/02/7bee4c1c-751c-44df-a318-d527916148f5.xlsU\x0fcontent_type_idq\nK\x17U\x0f_django_versionq\x0bU\x061.11.9U\ncreated_atq\x0ccdatetime\ndatetime\nq\rU\n\x07\xe2\x02\x02\x16\x188\x00\r\xd7cpytz\n_UTC\nq\x0e)Rq\x0f\x86Rq\x10U\x06_stateq\x11cdjango.db.models.base\nModelState\nq\x12)\x81q\x13}q\x14(U\x06addingq\x15\x89U\x02dbq\x16U\x07defaultq\x17ubU\nupdated_atq\x18h\rU\n\x07\xe2\x02\x02\x16\x188\x00\r\xf4h\x0f\x86Rq\x19U\tobject_idq\x1aNU\x07is_taskq\x1bK\x00U\x13_content_type_cacheh\x03U\x0ccontenttypesq\x1cU\x0bContentTypeq\x1d\x86\x85Rq\x1e}q\x1f(h\x0bU\x061.11.9U\x05modelq X... (220389b)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 592, in _receive_callback
        decoded = None if on_m else message.decode()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/message.py", line 142, in decode
        self.content_encoding, accept=self.accept)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 184, in loads
        return decode(data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 59, in _reraise_errors
        reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 55, in _reraise_errors
        yield
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 184, in loads
        return decode(data)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 64, in pickle_loads
        return load(BytesIO(s))
    DecodeError: ('model_unpickle() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)', , (('data_importer', 'FileHistory'),))
```

```
    Django==1.11.9
    celery==4.1.0
    billiard==3.5.0.3
    amqp==2.2.2
    data-importer==3.0.2
    kombu==4.1.0
```

Comment: pickle does not handle functions well

Comment: Can you also add the code for your task, and if this is happening in Django maybe a few more details like the views.py or models.py where the task is called from

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to resolve this but I faced the exact same issue this morning and traced it back to pickle being sent a complex object which the producer could serialize but the consumer could not, causing a crash like the one described in your ticket.

The producer is running Celery 4.4 and the consumer 3.1.25. 99,5% of the messages is coming through with no issues. I had a look at the the required kombu versions for both Celery versions.

**Full list 4.4**

```
pytz>dev
billiard>=3.6.1,<4.0
kombu>=4.6.7,<4.7
vine==1.3.0
```

**Full list 3.1.25**

```
pytz>dev 
billiard>=3.3.0.23,<3.4
kombu>=3.0.37,<3.1
```

So the Kombu packages are different and you will not be able to run the same version of that while also having different Celery versions on the producer and consumer side. This is not a huge issue for us, we ended up running the jobs which were crashing synchronously as the errors popped up in sentry.io. We will update the consumers tomorrow so they will be running the same versions again and this should probably be resolved.